# Drupal 7 gallery teaser

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I've created a simple gallery in Drupal using a custom content type.  It's really just an article with an image field that can have an unlimited number of items.  I've created a custom template for this content type (node--gallery.tpl.php) and for the full page I'm satisfied with the look and feel.

The one thing I'm stuck on is displaying only the first few images in the teaser.  I want to display just the first row of images in the teaser (that first 3 images).  In the template file, `$content['field_images']` contains all the images for the gallery but `print render($content['field_images']` outputs all the images (as I would expect).

So, how do I get Drupal to just output the first three items from `$content['field_images']`?  An improvement I would be interested in is how would I get Drupal to output 3 random images although if I know how to cut down the number of images rendered I'm confident I can work that one out myself.

Comment: Well, what is that variables content? Is it a concatenated html string with `<img>` tags? Or is it an array?

Comment: @mario I'm guessing you don't know Drupal if you're asking.  I've updated the question with the full output of $content['field_images'], it's rather long...

Comment: Well why, no I don't. It's easy to take a guess on the limited information, but a variable dump would clear up your description.

Comment: @mario The var_dump of the variable is too large to post...  SO won't actually let me publish the post with it.

Comment: @mario Drupal uses pretty complex arrays to pass information around and the render function knows how to process the arrays correctly.  However, you have to pass the right part of the array to render() for it to work and I've tried a few things and can't seem to get it right.

Comment: Try http://pastebin.com/ to circumvent the SO prohibition.

Comment: @mario no offence meant but I think this is something that requires somebody with knowledge of Drupal.  The array really won't mean anything to somebody who doesn't know Drupal, it's not as simple as just grabbing some of the array elements and outputting them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your template, find the appropriate array structure that has the image file names in it. If you can't find it in `$content`, look at the var_dump output of `$node`. Write a `for` loop to iterate over the first three items and for each of these items call either [theme_image()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/theme_image/7) or if you have image styles you want to use, [theme_image_style()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--image--image.module/function/theme_image_style/7). Pass in the appropriate configuration array to either using the file name you retrieved from the array.

Comment: It ended up being a little easier than that.  Inside $content['field_images'], along with all the meta info (elements starting with '#') there are numbered elements.  The numbered elements appeared to be the full nodes associated with each of the images so I was able to do print render($content['field_images'][$i]) and get what I wanted.  Points to you as it's almost right if a little fluffy.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of doing a var_dump or iterating over the array why not install the devel module and make use of its dpm() function which gives a nice output.

Comment: I could have done.  Didn't think of it given I'd been working on the project since D7 alpha 4 when the devel module didn't exist for D7.